# Filter JSON object with flat arrays

Tags: javascript, json

I have JSON object with array pairs, like this:

> Object {x: Array[36159], y: Array[36159], year: Array[36159]}

Small sample as example:

```
{
    "x": [309339618361.619, 102862032084.12102, 72892839276.09761, 46463392384.54194, -39360182208.042145],
    "y": [13950252.45052416, 1158787.402385158, -4368238.261400843, 1339913.7393283844, 2085336.6277048483],
    "year": [1991, 1991, 1992, 1992, 1992]
}
```

I want to filter this object on year. If JSON data was array or key, value pairs, I could have used filter:

```
data.filter(function (x) {
    return x.year == 1991
});
```

but as JSON structure is pairs of flat arrays, I have no idea how to approach.

---

Desired results is this:

```
{
    "x": [309339618361.619, 102862032084.12102],
    "y": [13950252.45052416, 1158787.402385158],
    "year": [1991, 1991]
}
```

Comment: The fact that you received the data as JSON is irrelevant. Presumably you parsed the data into a JavaScript object, so that's what you are working with (see [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/218196))

Comment: So what is desired result in this case?

Comment: @NenadVracar I just updated my question

Comment: `filter()` is an array method but there is no outer array shown

Comment: `data.year.filter(function (x) {
        return x === 1991;
    });` ~~ that's what you want to do, right?

Comment: @KlaiderKlai that returns just years array, while I want to filter whole object on specific year

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a callback with the comparison and an array for the properties, you want apply the filter on.

```js
var object = {
        "x": [309339618361.619, 102862032084.12102, 72892839276.09761, 46463392384.54194, -39360182208.042145],
        "y": [13950252.45052416, 1158787.402385158, -4368238.261400843, 1339913.7393283844, 2085336.6277048483],
        "year": [1991, 1991, 1992, 1992, 1992]
    },
    result = {};

['x', 'y', 'year'].forEach(function (p) {
    result[p] = object[p].filter(function (a, i) {
        return object.year[i] === 1991;
    });
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reduce()` and add values by index of year that you want to filter by.

```js
var obj = {
  "x": [309339618361.619, 102862032084.12102, 72892839276.09761, 46463392384.54194, -39360182208.042145],
  "y": [13950252.45052416, 1158787.402385158, -4368238.261400843, 1339913.7393283844, 2085336.6277048483],
  "year": [1991, 1991, 1992, 1992, 1992]
}

var result = obj.year.reduce(function(r, e, i) {
  if (e == 1991) {
    r.x = (r.x || []).concat(obj.x[i]);
    r.y = (r.y || []).concat(obj.y[i]);
    r.year = (r.year || []).concat(obj.year[i])
  }
  return r;
}, {});

console.log(result)
```

Comment: I'm in doubt which answer to accept, so I decided to choose Nina's as she replied first. Thanks

Comment: without the check for every loop and while push is optimised for one element and concat for more and concat returns the whole array with the new items and the needed assignment. i go for push.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do a copy of `obj` and iterate the elements of the `year` property and remove which aren't equal to `1991`.

```
var obj = {

    x:    [309339618361.619, 102862032084.12102],
    y:    [13950252.45052416, 1158787.402385158],
    year: [1991, 1991]

},

    scan = {};

Object.assign(scan, obj);

for(var i = 0, len = scan.year.length; i < len; i ++) {

    if(scan.year[i] !== 1991) {

        scan.year.splice(i, 1);

    }

}

console.log(scan);
```